# C# Drawing Oracle Spatial Geometries

Tags: c#, oracle, drawing, spatial, autocad

I need to create a simple app which can display geometries from Oracle Spatial in C#.
These geometries are exported from AutoCAD Map 3D 2010 to Oracle Spatial.

I need to pan, zoom, manage layers of these objects, events (like right click to popup a contextual menu, potentially different for every object), creating/deleting points (maybe also other polygons): a sort of simple AutoCAD interface.

Should I look for an AutoCAD OEM license? Is there a drawing framework which can handle this or do I need to create my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Desktop App**

[SharpMap](http://sharpmap.codeplex.com/)

**Web solution**

Have a look at [Mapguide Open source project](http://mapguide.osgeo.org/)

It has a C# API and an Oracle provider.

Answer (score 0):

This might be painful to do, though if you really want to code it yourself, you can look at the 3D possiblities of WPF (and some other libs above it, see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/wpf3d/)).

Comment: Actually I don't need to draw in 3D but 2D for simplicity (my Z is always 0)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found anything that suits my need so I'm going to do it using managed DirectX (which is not simple but powerful at least).